# Catalina: /usr/sbin/accept command not found

Tags: applescript, catalina, sudo

I have an applescript with code below that had been working until Catalina 10.15 update, gives command not found error:

```
do shell script "sudo /usr/sbin/accept '2nd-flr-Library-rm228'" with administrator privileges
```

Looked at /usr/sbin/ and accept is not in the directory.  Has it been moved?   Or is another method now required?

The script installs a printer, the uses accept command to get user to put in authorization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to **macOS Catalina** the `accept` *command* was a *symlink* to `cupsaccept`.  So in **macOS Catalina**, use:

```
/usr/sbin/cupsaccept
```

---

In **macOS Mojave**, in **Terminal**:

```
$ which accept
/usr/sbin/accept
$ ls -l /usr/sbin/accept
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  10 Sep  7 21:22 /usr/sbin/accept -> cupsaccept
$
```

In **macOS Catalina**, in **Terminal**:

```
% which cupsaccept
/usr/sbin/cupsaccept
%
```